# HQL date query question

Tags: hibernate, hql

if I am expecting a Date object say for 2011-03-05

and I want to use HQL to pull everything in 2011-03, ignoring the day/05

something like **`where year(somecolumn) = year(datepassedin) and month(somecolumn) = month(datepassedin)`**

is it possible to do in HQL?

It seems to be pertty easy to do in SQL, but not in HQL

Answer (score 1):

Well HQL has year and month [expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) and you can feed it date objects just fine. So, just use a [Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/) object as usual, nothing fancy or complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried two different versions of this same query and in SQL Server, something like what you have `where year(somecolumn)` was significantly slower (by almost an order of magnitude) than a bracketing query.

You have to create two dates, one at the beginning of the range, and one at the end. Say that you have a string:

```
val data = "2011-03-05"
```

Somewhere create a convenient const for parsing the value:

```
val dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM")
```

And then:

```
val yearMonthString = data.substring(0, 7)

val fromValue = dateFormat.parse(yearMonthString)
val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(iPutATimeZoneHere)
c.setTime(fromValue)
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
val toValue = c.getTime
```

In your query, you'll have `where somecolumn >= :fromValue and somecolumn < :toValue`.

This code is written in Scala, but it uses standard Java libraries.